# Download GitLab Generic Package File using Deploy Token

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a project (A), with CI pipeline, in GitLab.  This pipeline has a dependency on a package from another project (B).  During the build of project A, I want to download the package from project B's package registry.  The packages are uploaded as (zip files) [generic packages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/index.html).  The projects are all private so I need some kind of access token to authenticate.

I'm trying to use [Deploy Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) as these seem to provide the required read_package_registry access scope.  However, I cannot find any documentation describing how to authenticate with a deploy token when downloading generic package files.

I'm using the following request, described in the previous link.

```
GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_B_id>/packages/generic/<package_name>/<package_version>/<package_file>
```

I have tried

- adding the deploy token username and password to the URL, basic/digest authentication
- Adding a header to the request `PRIVATE-TOKEN: [deploy-token]`
- Adding a header to the request `DEPLOY-TOKEN: [deploy-token]`
- Adding a header to the request `Authorization: Bearer [deploy-token]`
- I've also tried each of the above headers but with `[deploy-token-username][deploy-token]` as the value

I can't find documentation stating that I *can't* use a deploy token.

Does anyone have a working example of how to do this, or does anyone know if this is/isn't possible?

I can switch to a private access token, but I'd prefer to use the correct tool for the job, and that seems to be deploy tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been raised on gitlab.  Deploy tokens do not work for now.  It is currently tracked here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/284397

The workaround is to use a personal access token.

Answer (score 3):

This works since Gitlab 13.0. [As per documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#read-or-pull-packages), create a deploy token, and supply the username and password in the request. This is basic authentication, and with curl you can do so

```
curl --user "<deploy-token-username>:<deploy-token>" \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/24/packages/generic/my_package/0.0.1/file.txt"
```

Deploy tokens do not seem to work with `PRIVATE-TOKEN` or `Authorization` headers with bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for this answer too.

The docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/index.html#authenticate-to-the-package-registry) say

> To authenticate to the Package Registry, you need either a personal access token or CI job token.

No mention of Deploy Tokens. Those seem to be limited to docker, npm, etc.

Also, the Job Token you have in project B allows you to publish your artifact. But, the Job Token you have in project A does not seem to be authorized to download it.

I believe the answer is that you cannot use a Deploy Token, but I'd love to be proven wrong.